# Pinout question: Is this just a PCIe x8 slot in a proprietary card position?

Tags: identification, pcie

Can anyone tell if this is just a normal PCIe x8 slot in a funny position, or is it also an unusual (incompatible) pinout?

The differential pairs and the number of pins look about right but I thought I'd see if there is a PCIe expert who can comment.  This is a Cisco UCSC-MRAID12G-2GB card.

We might like to use it outside of a Cisco UCSC with an [8x PCIe slot ribbon cable](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/1/1b3ecb1459e1db0b2b2bdca64ffdab4e3b3332c6-2952326.pdf) if it appears to be normal PCIe and should be safe to plug into a normal PCIe slot.

[image: UCSC-MRAID12G-2GB]
[image: UCSC-MRAID12G-2GB]

Comment: It does superficially look like a PCIe pinout. The lane pairs visible on the bottom side are on the correct fingers for lanes 4-7, the short fingers on the top side match the PRSNT2 positions and the one short position on the bottom matches PRSNT1. Pic is a bit fuzzy - but it also looks like the +12V pins are connected together as expected. My bet is that it is a PCIe x8.

Comment: @brhans, see answer.

Comment: It looks like they used a regular PCI connector for PCIe here, that's weird.

Comment: @Hearth it turns out thats the case.  We gave it a shot and it worked!  See the link in the answer below for details if you're curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out, it **is** a PCIe interface and the extension cable worked.  Thanks @brhans for offering the added bit of confidence I needed to try this out!

Here is a Reddit article about the whole project that was spawned by @brhans' comment:

- [How to build an LSI "9480-24i" w/ 4GB Cache for < $200 in parts](https://www.reddit.com/r/storage/comments/xjpnwv/how_to_build_an_lsi_948024i_w_4gb_cache_for_200/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)